# What OpenGL functions modify vertex positions prior to the vertex shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, coordinates

Let's say there's a color render texture that is 1000 px wide, 500 px tall.  And I draw a quad with vertices at the four corners `(-1, -1, 0)`, `(1, -1, 0)`, `(-1, 1, 0)`, `(1, 1, 0)` to it without any transformation in the vertex shader.

Will this always cover the entire texture's surface by default, assuming no other other GL functions prior to this sole draw command were called?

What OpenGL functions (that modify vertex positions) could cause this quad to no longer fill the screen?

(I'm trying to understand how vertices can be messed with prior to the vertex shader, so I can avoid or use the right functions to always map them so NDC `(-1, -1)` to `(1, 1)` represents the entire surface).

*edit:*  If the positions are not altered, then I'm also wondering how their mapping to a render buffer might be modified prior to the vertex shader.  For instance, will `(-1, -1, 0)` reliably refer to a fragment at the bottom-left of the render buffer, `(0, 0, 0)` to the middle, and `(1, 1, 0)` to the top-right?

Comment: What do you observe exactly? It doesn't fill the whole screen or you see nothing? Note that the z-coordinates are 0. If you are using a depth test, this might discard the fragments.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé - There's no depth/stencil testing, I'm mostly asking so I can understand how OpenGL modifies positions prior to the vert shader fully, so I can write my camera/drawing code more deliberately.  (right now it's mostly "it works somehow")

Comment: Okay, I understand. No, nothing modifies the vertex coordinates between the VBO and the start of the Vertex Shader. The data you send is the one you are receiving.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé - Aw, I see!  That makes sense.  I've edited the question to also ask how those positions might be made to draw to different fragment positions, or clipped altogether, outside of the vertex shader

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question: Vertex data usually contain the position and the texture coordinates (UV) of every vertex. The texture coordinates are used in the fragment shader to map the vertex to a pixel in image space. However, it is possible to avoid using texture coordinates for simple full screen quad drawing by using/transforming the position coordinates.

Comment: From that point, it might be easier to help you fix you problem if you provide your vertex and fragment shader code.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé - ah, sorry!  There's no UVs in this case, the texture in this case is the renderbuffer being drawn to.  I'm basically asking if there's anything that would make it so a vertex at (-1, -1), drawn as a single point, would *not* draw a fragment to the bottom left most pixel of the render buffer. (edited the question to clear that up)

Comment: @AnneQuinn Does the viewport rectangle ([`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml)) match to the size of the (default) framebuffer (respectively window)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 - It does

Comment: @AnneQuinn *"For instance, will (-1, -1, 0) reliably refer to a fragment at the bottom-left of the render buffer, (0, 0, 0) to the middle, and (1, 1, 0) to the top-right?"* the mapping of normalized device coordinates to the framebuffer is defined by the viewport ([`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml)). (-1, -1) is the bottom left of the viewport rectangle and (1, 1) the top right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing happens to vertex data "prior to the vertex shader". Nothing can happen to it, because OpenGL doesn't know what the vertex attributes *mean*. It doesn't know what attribute 2 refers to; it doesn't know what is a position, normal, texture coordinate or anything. As far as OpenGL is concerned, it's all just data. What gives that data meaning is your vertex shader. And only in the way defined by your vertex shader.

Data from buffer objects are read in accord with the format specified by your VAO, and are given to the vertex shader invocations which process those vertices.